# Changing accordion behaviour

Tags: jquery, html

I have used a little plugin called tinyAccordion, and I want to change the behaviour of it, but I'm just really doing this to teach myself some skills on accordions, and I'm kind of clueless on how to change it so the accordion opens only one tab at a time. To clarify, if you open another tab, the one that is open, closes.

I have the following code for this one:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");
    parentAccordion.init("acc","h6",0,0);

    var nestedAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("nestedAccordion");
    nestedAccordion.init("nested","h6",0,0,"acc-selected");

    </script>
```

Here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/LQsV5/

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net with your issue or a http://jsbin.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LQsV5/ I might be missing something, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a plugin, just try this couple of lines I wrote for you:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQsV5/2/)*

```
$('.acc li h3').next('.acc-section').hide();
$('.acc li h3').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).next('.acc-section');
    check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.acc-section').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
});
```

It will hide already opened tabs but also hide the opened one if clicked again.
If you have questions just ask!

Comment: That's great, thank you! How can I add so it opens the last tab by default?

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 **Simple:** use `$('.acc li h3').next('.acc-section:not(:eq(6))').hide();` just set instead of 6 **any number** you want opened by default. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LQsV5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
parentAccordion.init("acc","h6",0,0);
```

&

```
nestedAccordion.init("nested","h6",0,0,"acc-selected");
```

to

```
parentAccordion.init("acc","h6",1,0);
```

&

```
nestedAccordion.init("nested","h6",1,0,"acc-selected");
```